# Why can I not vertically align a button in a div in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I have spent way more time on this than any human should, I been through at least 30 solutions on Stack before posting this, as I know it is a VERY common issue. So I apologize for making my own post but I truly cannot get it working.

My code is below:

```html
      <div style="width: 100%">
        <div style="width: 70%; float: left;">
          <mat-form-field appearance="standard" >
            <mat-label>Filter Table Data</mat-label>
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="filter" (keyup)="applyFilter($event)">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 30%; float: right;">
          <button
          stye="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;"
          mat-raised-button (click)="clearFilter(1)" >
          Clear Filter 
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is how it displays on my site:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can get it working to be vertically aligned?

**End result goal:** the button ("Clear Filter") shown in the image needs to be vertically aligned, currently it shows at the top of the div.

Comment: Please improve your explanation, make it more clear what do you want to accomplish, maybe you could post image of desired solution.

Comment: Added the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution is to have flex container as parent. That allows you to easily align and justify its children.

Also using `float` is deprecated, so I'd recommend you to use `flexbox` or `grid` instead of `float`.

```
  <div
    style="
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
    "
  >
    <div style="width: 70%">
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
        <mat-label>Filter Table Data</mat-label>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="filter" (keyup)="applyFilter($event)">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 30%">
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="clearFilter(1)">Clear Filter</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Another and probably more suitable solution would be to use `Angular Flex Layout`. You can check out [Angular Flex Layout documentation](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs).

This is the solution for this particular case.

In order to use it, you need to import `FlexLayoutModule` and make it available in entire application.

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
```

Once the set up is done, this is how you use it to solve this problem:

```
  <div style="width: 100%" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
    <div style="width: 70%">
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
        <mat-label>Filter Table Data</mat-label>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="filter" (keyup)="applyFilter($event)">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="clearFilter(1)">Clear Filter</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This worked great thank you! On the Flexbox front -- is this now native or does it require an npm install? It seems like the "old" flex portion of Angular is also deprecated. Any links to docs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Flexbox is built in feature in css so you can use it straight away. But in Angular you can use `Angular Flex-Layout` which is a great thing. It allows you to set all flex and layout properties straight in HTML template, without using css. Also you need to install flex module in order to use it. Here is the link: https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

Comment: @user68288 I'll update my answer, to give some more information on how to solve this problem using `Angular Flex Layout`. Please add `angular` tag on your question since this applies only to angular.

Comment: @user68288 I've updated it, so you can see which solution fits you better, but I'd recommend you to always use `Angular Flex Layout` when using angular.

Comment: When I made the update using Angular Flex Layout it actually moves the clear button down a line. Any idea why? @Jovana

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249326/discussion-between-user68288-and-jovana).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="width: 100%;display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;">
            <div style="width: 70%; float: left;">
              <mat-form-field appearance="standard" >
                <mat-label>Filter Table Data</mat-label>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="filter" (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" >
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 30%;float: right;display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;">
              <button
              mat-raised-button (click)="clearFilter(1)" >
              Clear Filter 
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

might be work for you.